# Problems with LecoS plugin in QGIS on Mac Mojave

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-3

I wanted to install LecoS plugin in Qgis. But **first error appears that I have to instal scipy for python in orderd to use plugin.**

Python was instaled using instructions from Qgis document, version 3.6.5. Qgis version 3.6.2.

1. If i try to find the python in terminal :

$ python

Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:17:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

$ which python

/usr/bin/python

$ pyhton3

Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 05:52:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

$ which python3

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

2. and i already successfully installed all 3 using pip3

$ pip3 install numpy

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Julijas-Air:~ julijametic$ pip3 install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/b1/6e0c995d7646b12112a721e93dc6316409cc4827c10ee309747f45ea6bfd/scipy-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scipy)
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.2.1
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Julijas-Air:~ julijametic$ pip3 install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/7e/184d995d711e3401722769cd6982b46d42aee14a82ba54a3a79425f939c9/matplotlib-3.0.3-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/d9/3ec19e966301a6e25769976999bd7bbe552016f0d32b577dc9d63d2e0c49/pyparsing-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/5d/d1726d2a2fd471a69ef5014ca42812e1ccb8a13085c42bfcb238a5611f39/kiwisolver-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/d2/e07d3ebb2bd7af696440ce7e754c59dd546ffe1bbe732c8ab68b9c834e61/cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib)
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, kiwisolver, cycler, matplotlib
Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.1.0 matplotlib-3.0.3 pyparsing-2.4.0
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

3. But then trying to import it:

$ import numpy

-bash: import: command not found

$ python3

Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 05:52:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > numpy
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined

*So I dont know if it works or not now?*

After I went to try to install plugin again, but another error appears:
**Couldn't load plugin 'LecoS' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method** 
Does it again have to do something with the python?

I am not a programmer, and have really small experience with QGis.

Comment: It seems that you've tried to import numpy in bash instead of the python shell. Type `python3` first and then import numpy.

Comment: $ python3
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 05:52:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
>>> import matplotlib
>>>

Comment: So this works now if no error appears?
What about Couldn't load plugin 'LecoS' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method?

Comment: I manage to install PIL using pillow, and it looks like it worked. It installed the plugin without error. yey